# Moodle implementing Single Sign On

Tags: php, moodle

I'm using php LDAP admin for LDAP service. How to i can go to moodle site without inserting username and password again after i have logged in to my root website?(moodle site placed in my root website.

I have tried answer in this question:[Moodle Accept Login from external site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017713/moodle-accept-login-from-external-site)

But it still doesn't work

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Moodle’s authentication methods: https://docs.moodle.org/en/Authentication

Take the **CAS server** plugin in consideration for SSO.